# PHP - read HTML input from a form

Tags: php, html

I have a form that will dynamically send emailers . This form takes the email id of the recipient ,the subject and the body content.

I am using PHPMailer class to go about this. When it comes to plain text ,the emailers work just fine. But I want to add a functionality where the users can paste html into the body part so that the emailer can parse/read them and send the html'ized version of the emails.

I tried this , but it didn't work as the the entire HTML was mailed as text.

```
$email_msg = htmlentities($_POST['mail_msg'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
```

Any advice would be helpful .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Content-type: text/html`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you set the PHPMailer default to HTML:

```
$mail->IsHTML(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your mail headers :

```
$header  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-type: text/html; charset: utf8\r\n";
```

Comment: Thank you for responding..the above solution helped and worked.

Comment: It's okay, it's better anyway. I'm being old I need to read php doc again.